# Webview not displaying html

Tags: android, webview

My webview in my application does not show up. I went to the interwebs to find an answer, but I found nothing, just tutorials on how to use the control. I am trying to load a html file, but it is not showing.

I added the user permission 'Internet' to my manifest.

Here is my layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I have a file, 'filename.html' in my assets folder.

The following code is in the onCreate:

```
  WebView wvinfo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvInfo);
  wvinfo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

When I load the program on my phone, nothing shows up. I also tried to load an url, "http://www.google.com" and still nothing shows. I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: On local files, i would use `loadData(html, "text/html", null);`. You could also show us the manifest, or the parts you edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in your layout file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't setContent the layout inside `onCreate()`.

Try like this ...

`setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a Table Layout for a Web view? Instead use a Linear or Relative Layout.

Try adding this

```
WebView wvinfo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvInfo);
        wvinfo .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
       wvinfo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have RelativeLayout or LinearLayout as a parent layout to Webview??? I don't think so.....

Comment: @user2252502: it is not necessary .try the below code   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

 

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   
</TableLayout>

Comment: It is not necessary. Using table row too doesn't seem too good. So in order to remove table row I told so as done by Praveena.

Comment: @Oam Why you have enabled the JS here? When it might not be necessary